# How would I use INTO with SELECT AS in Oracle PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

As an example below, I am trying to figure out how I can use INTO (I have out parameters defined in a procedure I have made) when I am doing a SELECT statement that involves AS:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(addresses) AS TotalAddresses INTO outVar1, SUM(salary + tax) AS test INTO outVar2
FROM ...
```

Unfortunately, the compiler does not like this and well I have tried searching online, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `into` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(addresses) AS TotalAddresses, SUM(salary + tax) AS test 
INTO outVar1, outVar2
FROM ...
```

The results are going into variables.  There is no need to select `NAME` if it is not going to a variable.